# RSpec: Method stub in factory bot definition file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, attr-encrypted

I have a model, which is using `attr_encrypted` gem to encrypt the password.

```
class Credential < ApplicationRecord
  validates :user_name, presence: true
  enum credential_type: { windows: 1, linux: 2 }

  attr_encrypted :user_pass, key: :encryption_key

  def encryption_key
    # Some complex logic
  end
end
```

I am learning to write test cases and my factory for the above looks like this:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :credential do
    user_name { "rmishra" }
    user_pass { "secret" }
    credential_type { "linux" }
    encryption_key { "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw123456789" }
  end
end
```

My spec file looks like:

```
RSpec.describe Credential, type: :model do
  let(:credential) { create(:credential) }
  ...
end
```

How do I stub `encryption_key` method in factory definition, which is getting used at the time of `create`?

Answer (score 2):

Since `encryption_key` is not an attribute on your model, you can't configure it in your factory.

`encryption_key` is called automatically by the `attr_encrypted` gem when you assign `user_pass` to a `Credential` object. In this case that's done by the factory.

I would move the logic in your `encryption_key` method into a class to facilitate testing:

```rb
class Credential < ApplicationRecord
  validates :user_name, presence: true
  enum credential_type: { windows: 1, linux: 2 }

  attr_encrypted :user_pass, key: :encryption_key

  def encryption_key
    EncryptionKeyGenerator.generate # or whatever name makes more sense
  end
end
```

Then, in my test, I would stub the `EncryptionKeyGenerator`:

```rb
RSpec.describe Credential, type: :model do
  let(:credential) { create(:credential) }
  let(:encryption_key) { "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw123456789" }

  before do
    allow(EncryptionKeyGenerator).to receive(:generate).and_return(encryption_key)
  end

  ...
end
```

Encapsulating your encryption key generation logic into a separate object decouples it from your model, allowing you to easily test that logic without having to create a `Credential` object.